# Llenar un select html por medio de un ciclo en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, bucles

Quiero llenar un select dinámicamente con años, partiendo del año 2000 al 2050, a través de un ciclo for en javascript. Pero aún no me funciona el código.

HTML

```
<select id="año">
</select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
select = document.getElementById("año");
option = document.createElement("option");
for(i = 2000; i <= 2050; i++){
  option.value = i;
  option.text = i;
}
select.appendChild(option);
```

Y al final solo me crea un solo option con el valor de 2050.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```js
select = document.getElementById("año");
for(i = 2000; i <= 2050; i++){
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = i;
    option.text = i;
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="año"> </select>
```

Por cada iteración en el ciclo `for` debes de crear un elemento `option` y de igual manera agregarselo al elemento `select`.

Comment: ¡Genio! Muchas gracias, no es tan evidente el error cuando lo examina uno mismo!

Comment: Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como valida. Saludos

Comment: solo por mejorar , puedes trabajar sin la ñ te puede dar errores a futuro dependiendo la codificacion de donde te ubiques

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución amigo:

```js
select = document.getElementById("año");
for(i = 2000; i <= 2050; i++){
  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = i;
  option.text = i;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="año">
</select>
```

Comment: pues funcionará aqui pero como que lago falta, lo estoy chyecando en el entorno web de mi computadora tratando de programarla y no sale nada, ni un numero, alguna libreria let car o algo por el estilo?